# In shell script, how to go into a file and replace every instance of a string with an iterating timestamp

Tags: bash, logging

I need to go into a directory of a few thousand files worth of log entries that contains each string of format:

```
timestamp: REPLACE_ME
```

and replace each instance of it with a DIFFERENT iterative datetime of around 5 minutes increment.

I.e:

```
first instance of "REPLACE_ME" -> March,1,2020: 00:00:05 
second instance of "REPLACE_ME" -> March,1,2020: 00:00:10
...
...
...
nth instance of "REPLACE_ME" -> March,1,2020 23:55:55
```

and then "loop around"

```
n+1th instance of "REPLACE_ME" -> March,1,2020, 00:00:00
```

I tried something like

```
sed -i "0,/${REPLACETEXT}/ s/${REPLACETEXT}/${DATE_VAR}/" ${FILE}
```

in a loop, but this is so inefficient (minutes to process a file a few MBs) that it's not acceptable.

The purpose of why I'm doing this is I'm trying to generate "fake logs" with increment timestamp where every event takes place at exactly a 5 min interval. Unfortunately, the Json Log generator solution I'm using (log-synth) doesn't support incremental timestamps. So I'm trying to figure out how to do this in Bash.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `date` command to increment a datetime and return a value in your expected format:

```
$ TZ=UTC date --date='2020-03-01 00:00:00Z + 5 minutes' '+%B,%d,%Y %H:%M:%S'
March,01,2020 00:05:00
```

Then you need to loop over the contents of the file like this (untested):

```
current_date='2020-03-01 00:00:00Z'
while IFS= read -r line
do
    sed -i "s/REPLACE_ME/$(TZ=UTC date --date="$current_date" +%B,%d,%Y %H:%M:%S)/" "$line"
    current_date="$(TZ=UTC date --date="$current_date + 5 minutes")"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Pure bash (using builtins).  Wraps around after 24hrs without changing the day.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

date="March 1, 2020"

ts=0
re='^(timestamp: )REPLACE_ME$'

while IFS= read -r line ; do
    [[ $line =~ $re ]] && {
        line="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}$(printf "%s %02d:%02d:%02d" "$date" $((ts/3600)) $(((ts/60)%60)) $((ts%60)))"
        let 'ts=(ts+5)%86400' # advance by 5 seconds, wrap after 24hrs
        #let 'ts=(ts+300)%86400' # advance by 5 minutes, wrap after 24hrs
    }
    printf "%s\n" "$line"
done
```